# This php code is only picking up the first row in my database. Help?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","","root") or die(mysql_error());
$objDB = mysql_select_db("mydb");
$pic2 = "SELECT * FROM thumbs";
if (!isset($_GET['Page']))  $_GET['Page']='0';
$pic1 = mysql_query($pic2);
$Num_Rows = mysql_num_rows($pic1);
$Per_Page = 16;   // Per Page
$Page = $_GET["Page"];
if(!$_GET["Page"])
{
    $Page=1;
}
$Prev_Page = $Page-1;
$Next_Page = $Page+1;
$Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
{
    $Num_Pages =1;}
    else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
    {
        $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
    }
    else
    {
        $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
        $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;}
        $pic2 .=" order  by thumbnailID ASC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
        $pic1  = mysql_query($pic2);
        $cell = 0;
        $link1 = "SELECT * FROM thumbs";
        $result_link1 = mysql_query($link1);
        $link = mysql_fetch_array($result_link1);
        $alt1 = "SELECT * FROM thumbs";
        $alt = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($alt1));
        $height1 = "SELECT * FROM thumbs";
        $height = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($height1));
        $width1 = "SELECT * FROM thumbs";
        $width = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($width1));
        $time1 = "SELECT * FROM thumbs";
        $time = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($time1));
        $folder1 = "SELECT * FROM thumbs";
        $folder = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($folder1));
        $filed1 = "SELECT * FROM thumbs";
        $filed = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($filed1));
        echo '
         <div id="tablediv">
         <table border="0" cellpadding="17" cellspacing="0" class="table">
         <tr>';

        while($pic = mysql_fetch_array($pic1))
        {
            if($cell % 4 == 0)
            {
                echo '</tr><tr>';
            }
        {
        echo'
         <td>
          <a href="/' . $link["link"] . '">
            <div class="image"><img src="' . $pic["pic"] . '"
                   alt="' . $alt["alt"] . '" 
                   height="' . $height["height"] . '" 
                   width="' . $width["width"] . '" 
              />
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="timeago">
            <abbr class="timeago" title="' . $time["time"] .'">
           </abbr>&nbsp;in <a href="/' . $folder["folder"] . '">
           <span class="filedat">' . $filed["filed"] . '</div></a>
          </div>
        </td>'; 
    }
    $cell++;
  }
  echo '</tr></table></div>';
?>
```

I'm a noobie, and I have no idea why this code is only picking up the first row in my mysql database. Here's what I mean.
My phpmyadmin db looks like:

```
thumbnailID |    link    |     pic     |   alt   | time | height | width | folder | filed
     1           blog      random.png    descrip   3:45    300      200      emm     weewr 
     2           about      etc.png      desc      4:15    130      150      wer     ewrre
     3           misc       er.png        desc     2:30    324      435      sdf     dcv
     4           misc        etc.png      info     6:50    203      034      sdf      qwd
     5           about       meh.png       whoa    10:12   395      234      tb      asd
```

So as you can see, there is five different rows. But for some reason, row 2,3,4, and 5, all have the same link, alt, time height, width, folder, and filed, as row 1. The only thing different is the pic.

For if this sounds confusing, but I don't know how to put it in any other way.

Comment: Why all the duplicated SELECT statements, none of which have a WHERE clause? Is that what you are saying? The each SELECT returns the same thing? If so, of course they do, since they all ask for the same thing. I'd recommend cutting this down to the actual problem, and working from there, without dealing with all the crap about formatting.

Comment: Hey! I will not talk about the security holes in your code. I will just ask you: Why is there about 15 queries to get a resultset? There is something really awkward in the way you are doing this. Please explain clearly what it is you want this code to do and I am pretty sure you can do this in about 1/4 of the code you have.

Comment: Also you should really adopt a better (or any) code indention habit first. It's near impossible to follow the processing logic else.

Comment: Stef, I am trying to create something like an image gallery. Except those images are links are links too? I realized after reading mario's suggestion, I could trim everything from $link1 to $filed. What else can I delete? Also, I know this is coding horror to many. I never code. I'm just trying to get my site hah. I know very little of mysql and php as it is.

Comment: @mario +1 I would also like the proper indents within the code to not spend whole day reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are issuing multiple [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) requests, which always resets the pointer to the first row. But [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) is to be used in a loop. It also queries for rows, not column-wise.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM thumbs");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    print "   <td> $row[link] + $row[pic] + $row[alt] ";

    // use only the loop variable here, not the static request arrays
    // from before
}
```

Your problem is that you are using previous result arrays $link[], $pic[], $alt[], $width[], $height[] for your output code - where you should be using just `$row` (or `$pic` in your code).

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) states,

```
mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both
```

One row, you see.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [small example](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlselect.php) I handpicked for you. Read it and look at it closely until you understand how it gets the table printed. This will help you do the script you posted in a more concise and clear manner.

Happy coding, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Teste with MYSQLI and fetch_object:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$password = "12345";
$database = "database";

try {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        throw new Exception('Fail to connect to the database!');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("No connection: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
       while($row = $result->fetch_object())
       {
          $i++;
          echo "line$i $row->field_name";
       }
    }
```