# How to select all rows with same value?

Tags: php, mysql, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL returns only one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372197/mysql-returns-only-one-row)

I wonder how to select all rows with a single value. EG all rows where the column username is a certain username. Here is the code I have at this moment:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from `order` WHERE username='$user'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
echo $row['username'];
echo $row['amount'];
```

This echos only the values in the first row. Any help would be great.

Comment: You need to fetch in a loop.  `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {echo $row['username']; }`

Comment: Thank you, do you also know how I can seperate each of these values?

Comment: What do you mean separate? Like put a space between? `echo $row['username'] . " ";` or a line break ` . '<br />'`

Comment: [Another example question...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169518/this-php-code-is-only-picking-up-the-first-row-in-my-database-help)

Comment: in table as <table><tr><td>USERNAME</td><td>amount</td></tr> ... HERE this GOES INSIDE LOOP:<tr><td><?=$row['username']?></td><td><?=$row['amount']?></td></tr> LOOP END </table>

Comment: Well I have to make each value of for example amount (a column in my table) a variable. But now it would be all values in one variable. Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: @user1760791 You need to build your loop accordingly. If each value belongs in a cell in a column, the loop should include the creation of the surrounding `<tr><td> </tr></td>`

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_fetch_array only pulls one row from $result at a time.

Try:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
{
    echo $row['username'];
    echo $row['amount'];

}
```